# Map/match fruitColors with fruits using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've two objects, one with fruit colors:

```
fruitColor = {
    'color': "Yellow",
    'fruits': []
}
```

And the second with fruits:

```
fruits = {
    'title': "Banana",
    'color': "Yellow"
}
```

How can I match the both .color (and add/push fruits to fruitColor.fruits) in a simple way? Both colors and fruits contains multiple.

I've tried jQuery .map() and .each() but not sure how to use it in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.each(fruits,function(i,v){
   $.each(fruitColor,function(i2,v2){
      if (v.color == v2.color)
        v2.fruits.push(v.title);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't your objects array of object ? More like this :

```
fruitColor = [{
    'color': "Yellow",
    'fruits': []
   },
   {
     'color': "Green",
     'fruits': []
   }]

fruits = [{
        'title': "Banana",
        'color': "Yellow"
      },
      {
        'title': "Apple",
        'color': "Green"
      }];
```

If it is, you can do :

```
for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){
   for (var j = 0; j < fruitColor.length; i++){
      if (fruitColor[j].color == fruits[i].color)
        fruitColor[j].fruits.push(fruits[i].title);
        break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Although Robin 's code is correct, the idea of changing objects to array was usefull for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check this with `for in` loop:

```js
var fruitColor = {
    'color': "Yellow",
    'fruits': []
},
fruits = {
    'title': "Banana",
    'color': "Yellow"
}

for(key in fruitColor){
  if(fruitColor.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    if(fruits[key] === fruitColor[key]){
       fruitColor.fruits.push(fruits["title"])
    }
  }
}

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(fruitColor.fruits) +'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your objects it self are json objects you can simly compare them by gettinf `Object.property` value.

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3sLmopd9/1/)

```
fruitColor = {
    'color': "Yellow",
    'fruits': []
}

fruits = {
    'title': "Banana",
    'color': "Yellow"
}

$(document).ready(function(){

 if(   fruitColor.color == fruits.color){
 fruitColor.fruits.push(fruits);

 }

    console.log( fruitColor.fruits);


});
```